# Why won't salesforce recognize relative URL?

Tags: pagereference, url

On clicking a button my visualforce page is supposed to redirect to the saveURL defined in my get parameters.

The saveURL is literally just the ID of an object (usually an account), here is the apex:

```
PageReference contactPage = new PageReference('/' + saveURL);
contactPage.setRedirect(true);
return contactPage;
```

It should be "https://na15.salesforce.com/saveURL". But instead it's "https://na15.salesforce.com/https://c.na15.salesforce.com/saleURL". How do I stop this?

Comment: It looks like your saveURL value is a fully qualified URL already. Is it not usable as is i.e. just remove the "'/' +"?

Comment: I don't understand. This is the URL of the page before: https://c.na15.visual.force.com/apex/SMSSendSingle?recipient=003i000000fwtvR&saveURL=003i000000fwtvR, as you can see the save URL is not a fully qualified URL it is just an ID.

Comment: That looks like a valid Visualforce page URL that should just work passed into the constructor like this `new PageReference(saveURL)`.

Comment: Ah I see. Stupid how I had to get rid of the '/' yet it says in the official documentation that having a slash before a partial URL is ok.

Comment: Your case is a full URL not a partial one.

Comment: @KeithC you should post that as the answer. That is the right solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As confirmed in the comment thread, the `saveURL` value was already fully qualified so adding a slash in the code (implying that the URL is relative and so needed converting into a full URL) was the wrong thing to do. So the fix in this case is to just remove the slash prefix:

```
PageReference contactPage = new PageReference(saveURL);
```